# Closed form of $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \ln \left(\frac{1}{|x-y|}\right) \frac{4}{(1+|y|^2)^2} dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, vector-analysis, closed-form

While reading a paper I stumbled across the integral
$$
\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \ln \left(\frac{1}{|x-y|}\right) \frac{4}{(1+|y|^2)^2} d^2y\,,
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is fixed. I think the paper implicitly claims that this is equal to $-2 \pi \ln (1+|x|^2)$.

I'm not sure if this is a hard integral at all, but considering the amount of proficient integrators on this site, I thought that I should post this question here.

To provide some context, the term $\ln \frac{1}{|x-y|}$ comes from the Laplacian's Green function (it is the leading term near $x$) and the term $\frac{4}{(1+|y|^2)^2}$ is of course the "density" of the stereographic projection metric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note the result
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\!d\phi\, \ln(a^2- 2a b \cos(\phi) +b^2) = 4\pi \ln[\max(|a|,|b|)] \tag{1}$$
which can be proven by different methods (e.g., by taking the derivative with respect to $a$ or $b$).

Your integral is given by (using polar coordinates $(r,\phi)$)
$$I= \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\!d^2y \ln\left(\frac{1}{|x-y|}\right) \frac{4}{(1+|y|^2)^2}
= -\int_0^\infty \!r dr\int_{0}^{2\pi} \!d\phi \, \ln(|x|^2 - 2 |x| r\cos \phi + r^2) \frac{2}{(1+r^2)^2}   .$$

With the result (1), we obtain
$$ I = - 4\pi\int_0^\infty\!dr \frac{2 r}{(1+r^2)^2} \ln[\max(|x|,|r|)]
= -4\pi \ln |x| \int_0^{|x|}\!dr\,\frac{2r}{(1+r^2)^2} -4\pi \int_{|x|}^\infty\!dr\,\frac{2 r \ln r}{(1+r^2)^2} \\
=  -\frac{4\pi |x|^2 \ln |x|}{1+|x|^2} - 2\pi\left[ \frac{2r^2 \ln r}{1+r^2} -\ln (1+r^2) \right]_{r=|x|}^\infty = -2\pi \ln(1+|x|^2)$$

Comment: Good catch! (+1)